# Istio ingress-controller via host network (bare-metal)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, istio, bare-metal-server

I am trying to use of Istio in bare-metal and I wanted to use the minimum resources needed just to get an Ingress controller with Envoy and Cert-Manager (maybe later evolving to the use of more advanced service mesh features). I tried following this docs: [Istio Kubernetes Ingress with Cert-Manager](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-certmgr/) Demonstrates how to obtain Let's Encrypt TLS certificates for Kubernetes Ingress automatically using Cert-Manager.

My main problem is that I am in bare-metal and want to use neither LoadBalancer nor NodePort. I was going for a host-network approach as the analogous solution using nginx [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/#via-the-host-network). 1) Can I use istio to replace my current nginx-ingress controller with Hostnetwork?

Setup tried (with no success):

```
helm install install/kubernetes/helm/istio-init --name istio-init --namespace istio-system
helm install install/kubernetes/helm/istio --name istio --namespace istio-system \
--values install/kubernetes/helm/istio/values-istio-minimal.yaml
```

2) If (1) is possible, can I use istio helm chart with istio-minimal (just istio-pilot) for that? What is the recommended minimal profile setup in this case?

Answer (score 2):

The *istio.io* document for [Ingress with Cert-Manager](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-certmgr/) needs you to use the `ingress-gateway` object to attach it to a load balancer, so it's not an alternative in this case.

The Nginx approach is feasible as [you can use Cert-Manager with the Nginx ingress class](https://docs.cert-manager.io/en/latest/tutorials/acme/quick-start/) to automatically manage your certificates (replacing the Envoy-based Istio resources).

Now, the issue is that you have to redirect all the Nginx incoming traffic into the Istio mesh.

Although this is integration is not yet natively supported, [there are ways to make them work together](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/2126#issuecomment-367323042) that might end up rather hacky.

Unless you're having an issue that is not described in the question, I don't think having the minimal Istio installation has any relationship with this scenario.

Comment: Thanks Yahir. I think I wasn't clear about using nginx.. I want to use an analogue approach to the documentation I mentioned and REPLACE my nginx-ingress controller with istio. In the documentation you sent me says "By default istio-ingressgateway will be exposed as a LoadBalancer service type. You may want to change that by setting the gateways.istio-ingressgateway.type installation option to NodePort if this is more applicable to your Kubernetes environment.". As I am in bare-metal with no LoadBalancer and NodePort isn't an option for network restrictions, I need hostnetwork, is it possible?

Comment: I also want this